# Highlight one item of listview in android

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, imageview

I'm building a media player. I have a playlist which is an activity with a listview with custom adapter. An item in this listview contains 2 fields : . I want to make the image (playing) visible only for the song which is currently playing(in a service). Also, this should change dynamically whenever the song changes due to any reason even while the playlist activity is open.

Comment: you can modify your custom `ListAdapter` and override the `getView` method to get the position of current view. then change the background color using `view.setBackgroundColor`

Comment: Yes, sufiyan is right about the approach. One thing to add is that when the song changes, you can call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter to force it to redraw the views to show the selection change.

Comment: But would that not be processor intensive if there are many songs just for the sake of highlighting one song? Also, since the song change happens in a service and this is an activty, how would I call it from the service? I wouldn't have the activity's instance. What happens when the activity is not active? @Bruce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving to an answer ...

Yes, sufiyan is right about the approach. One thing to add is that when the song changes, you can call notifyDataSetChanged on your adapter to force it to redraw the views to show the selection change.

The biggest expense for drawing a ListView is constructing new item views, but if your adapter's getView uses the 'convertView' parameter then you save that expense. For notifying the activity, I would recommend sending a broadcast from your service. In your activity, register a receiver in onResume, and unregister it in onPause. Then in onResume make sure you refresh (in case the song changed while your activity was paused.